# Get list of Rails custom methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the list of methods defined in a Rails model without the attributes and reflections.

The code I have thus far is as follows but it only shows the database columns and has_many, etc definitions. I need the custom methods in the model as well.

```
    class.reflections.keys.each do |key|
      define_method key do
        @object.send key
      end
    end
    class.attribute_names.each do |sym|
      define_method sym do
        @object.send sym
      end
    end
```

I've tried ".methods", etc but it includes or excludes the methods I've defined.

Comment: You need `.instance_methods`

Comment: That returns all the parent methods as well. I need to find only the methods defined in the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MyClass.instance_methods(false)`, but make sure to pass `false` as an argument if you don't want it to return the methods defined in the superclasses.

Additionally, use `MyClass.singleton_methods(false)` for class methods.

More info:

- https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/singleton_methods
- https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/instance_methods

Comment: This also returns all the inherited methods which is not whats desired. I'm not sure this can be done in Ruby, so I went with a manual method declaration model which is not ideal but it works.